# Will releasing an array also release its elements?

Tags: objective-c

I alloc my `NSMutableArray`, and add objects that were `alloced` as well. Will calling `release` on my array also release the elements within, or do I have to release each element manually first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in obj-c collection are released when that collection is **deallocated** (that's not the same as being released). So in practice if you add your object in collection, collection manages its objects ownership and you don't need to put extra releases for its elements.

Comment: So I have to dealloc, and then release?

Comment: No, you need to release your array as much as you retained it and it will be deallocated automatically - and then its elements will be released

Comment: So 1 alloc = 1 release? Thanks.

Comment: @Omega, yes if you create object with alloc object's retainCount will be 1 and you'll need to release it sometime (e.g. either right away after you added it to collection or sending autorelease message to the object)

Answer (score 2):

Check the  [Collections Programming  Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/collections/Collections.html) guide. More  specifically, the
Arrays section and the Array Fundamentals topic:

> When  an array  is **deallocated**  in  a managed  memory environment,  each
>   element is sent a release message.

So if releasing an  array brings its retain  count to 0, and  it is then about
to be deallocated, at this point the objects will receive a `release` message.
Otherwise, releasing an  array just  decrements its retain count  as any other
regular object.

Also, when you place objects in the array, they receive a `retain` message, as
the guide explains.